# Framework - wildcard subdomain website.com/user/username to username.website.com

Tags: php, routes, subdomain, wildcard

I have a problem with wildcard subdomain routing. I have added `*.website.com` and add Server alias. `subdomain.website.com` shows `website.com`.

But I want `subdomain.website.com` to show `website.com/user/username/`. `print_r($_GET)` returns me `array([user/username] => )`.

PS: every another web pages (such as contact, about page etc) will be shown as `username.website.com/page` (Other examples: `username.website.com/contact`, `username.website.com/news/id/news-name.html` etc).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why -2 vote ???? Is this so bad or ununderstandable question ??

Answer (score 1):

1 configure your dns tô accept *.domain.com 
2 configure *.domain.com wildcard alias on apache vhost (search on google, have many tutorials) 
3 Get current domain name in $_SERVER PHP global variables, and make your own magic using logic. 
Obs: If you delay to configure your server, persist becouse is not so simple,  Don't forget restart apache after configure virtual host

Comment: And I don't need to use htaccess ?

Comment: You'll use .htaccess for friendly URL configuration but not to subdomain configuration

Comment: Htaccess I have already written and it works. :) but now I need to edit routing for subdomain

Answer (score 0):

If I go to url: subdomain.example.com/test -> print_r($_GET) shows me:

```
Array([user/subdomain], [test])
```

If I go to url: example.com/user/subdomain/test -> print_r($_GET) shows me:

```
Array([user/subdomain/test])
```

This is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (?!^$)^.*$ http://example.com/user/%1 [P,NC,L]
```

So, I have edited my code in Router in such way:

```
$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if(array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST', $_SERVER) && count($_GET) >= 2) {
        $subdomain = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
        $sub = str_replace('.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], '', $subdomain);
        $arr = array_keys($_GET);
        $uri = $uri.'/'.$arr['1'];
    }

if(array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST', $_SERVER) && count($_POST) >= 2) {
        $subdomain = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
        $sub = str_replace('.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], '', $subdomain);
        $arr = array_keys($_POST);
        $uri = $uri.'/'.$arr['1'];
    }
```

But I think there must be much better way. Would be very thankfull for help, advice :)

Comment: is anybody here ?

Answer (score 0):

Now it's only logic but I suggest avoid do unnecessary complex things on .htaccess, do the routing on PHP and only friendly URL on .htaccess, you can verify if is subdomain and mock the solution on PHP bootstrap index.php